# ¿Cómo puedo obtener datos de un usuario en especifico en Firebase para Android?

Tags: android, base-de-datos, firebase

He buscado la forma de cómo obtener los datos de un usuario especifico en Android Studio con la base de datos en Firebase, pero por el momento no encuentro nada, podrían ayudarme.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mis usuarios se identifican mediante el Correo Electrónico y tienen una sección donde ellos pueden ver solo los artículos que ellos han escrito, añadí esos valores porque son los que necesito a excepción de uid.
Que podría hacer para obtener solo los datos del usuario y llenarlos mediante un RecyclerViewAdapter y CardView.

Utilizo un fragment para llamarlos, el cual no carga a la primera vez, espero encontrar una solución.

```
public class MainOne extends Fragment {

public MainOne(){

}

//El Fragment va a cargar su layout, el cual debemos especificar
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_mainone, container, false);

    if(view instanceof RecyclerView){
        DbDreamsUsers dbDreamsUsers = DbDreamsUsers.getInstance();
        Context context = view.getContext();
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyDreamsUserRecyclerViewAdapter());
    }

    return view;
}
```

}

Este es mi RecyclerViewAdapter

```
public class MyDreamsUserRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyDreamsUserRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{
private DbDreamsUsers db;

public MyDreamsUserRecyclerViewAdapter(){
    db = DbDreamsUsers.getInstance();
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.carduser, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mItems = db.getDreamsList().get(position);
    holder.tvTitle_user.setText(holder.mItems.getTitulo());
    holder.tvAuthor_user.setText(holder.mItems.getAutor());
    holder.tvDate_User.setText(holder.mItems.getFecha());
    final String Dream, Title, Author, Date;
    Dream = (String)holder.mItems.getDream();
    Title = (String)holder.mItems.getTitulo();
    Author = (String)holder.mItems.getAutor();
    Date = (String)holder.mItems.getFecha();

    holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), activity_details.class);
            intent.putExtra("Title" , Title);
            intent.putExtra("Author" , Author);
            intent.putExtra("Date" , Date);
            intent.putExtra("Dream" , Dream);
            Context context = view.getContext();
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return db.getDreamsList().size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public final View mView;
    public final TextView tvTitle_user;
    public final TextView tvAuthor_user;
    public final TextView tvDate_User;
    public Sueños mItems;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
        tvTitle_user = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitleCard_user);
        tvAuthor_user = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAuthorCard_user);
        tvDate_User = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDate_user);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + " '" + tvTitle_user.getText() + "'";
    }
}
```

}

y por ultimo mi constructor.

```
public final class DbDreamsUsers {
private static final DbDreamsUsers INSTANCE = new DbDreamsUsers();
private static final String TAG = "DbDreamsUsers";

private FirebaseDatabase db;
private DatabaseReference usersRef;
private List<Sueños> dreamsList;
private FirebaseAuth auth;
private FirebaseUser user;

private DbDreamsUsers(){
    db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    dreamsList = new ArrayList<Sueños>();
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    user = auth.getCurrentUser();
    usersRef = db.getReference("articles"  ).child(auth.getUid());

    usersRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            dreamsList.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(Sueños.class));
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

public static DbDreamsUsers getInstance(){
    return INSTANCE;
}

public void addDreams(Sueños sueños){
    usersRef.push().setValue(sueños);
}

public List<Sueños> getDreamsList(){
    return dreamsList;
}
```

}

Se los agradecería mucho, disculpen si ya hay respuesta en otro lugar, pero intente aplicarlo sin resultado alguno, aún me encuentro estudiando lo que es Firebase.

Comment: que datos queres solicitar de los usuarios ?

Comment: Espero explicarme bien, me gustaría obtener los datos de cada item que haya generado cada usuario, es decir, por ejemplo obtener todos los datos que haya generado Bryan.

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver tu problema tienes que crear una clase en la cual vas a declarar lo que necesitas traer.

Primero crea la clase UserPojo.class la cual va a tener los datos que necesitas traer de Firebase para cada usuario.

```
public class UserPojo {

    private String autor;
    private String background;
    private String dream;
    private String fecha;
    private String titulo;
    private String uid;

    public UserPojo(){

    }

    public String getAutor() {
        return autor;
    }

    public String getBackground() {
        return background;
    }

    public String getDream() {
        return dream;
    }

    public String getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }

    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }

    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }




}
```

Ahora, con la referencia de cada usuario, obtenemos los elementos de cada uno de la siguiente manera

```
usersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    UserPojo user = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserPojo.class);
    //Obtenemos los valores de un usuario en especifico
     String autor = user.getAutor();
     String background = user.getBackground();
     String dream = user.getDream();
     String fecha = user.getFecha();
     String titulo = user.getTitulo();
     String uid= user.getUid();

       //Obteniendo el user id
       String uid = dataSnapshot.getKey();

      //puedes hacer lo que quieras con los datos


  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
  }
});
```

ahora, si quisieras tener todos los datos de todos los usuarios podes hacer esto

```
dg.getReference("articles").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

        UserPojo user = snapshot.getValue(UserPojo.class);
        //Obtenemos los valores de todos los usuarios
         String autor = user.getAutor();
         String background = user.getBackground();
         String dream = user.getDream();
         String fecha = user.getFecha();
         String titulo = user.getTitulo();
         String uid= user.getUid();

         //Obtener los uid de los usuarios desde este codigo
          String uid = snapshot.getKey();


         }

      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
      }
    });
```

Para mas info podes consultar [aca](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write?hl=es-419)

Comment: ¿Disculpa como obtengo la referencia de cada usuario?

Comment: con el auth.getUid conseguis la del usuario que esta logueado y usando la app en el momento, podes usar getKey() del snapshot para encontrar cada padre de esos nodos

Comment: ahi te modifique la respuesta, espero te sirva

Comment: pudiste lograrlo ? @VictorBryanChávez

Comment: Tuve unas complicaciones y estoy buscando el error :(